# Why doesnt @Host decorator works?

Tags: angular, decorator

I created the following hierarchy:

> app-component -> inner-component -> hover-directive

The directive colors the component it is applied to on mouseover. But the color is taken from the service. This service is registered with the injector via

> inner-component

.

The problem is that this service is injected in the directive and the constructor uses the @Host decorator. As I understand it, the search for a service should occur in the component to which the directive is applied, that is, in the

> inner-component

. However, this does not happen, this is the problem. Please help me fix the script.

[live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/at-ng-14-router-tqjnrl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhover.directive.ts)

directive:

> ```
> @Directive({
>   // providers: [ColorService],
>   selector: '[appHover]',
> })
> export class HoverDirective implements OnInit {
>   color: string;
>
>   constructor(
>     private elementRef: ElementRef,
>     private renderer: Renderer2,
>     @Optional() @Host() private colorService: ColorService
>   ) {}
>
>   ngOnInit() {
>     this.color = this.colorService?.color;
>     console.log('---', this.color);
>   }
>
>   @HostListener('mouseenter') mouseover() {
>     this.renderer.setStyle(
>       this.elementRef.nativeElement,
>       'background-color',
>       this.color
>     );
>   }
>
>   @HostListener('mouseleave') mouseleave() {
>     this.renderer.setStyle(
>       this.elementRef.nativeElement,
>       'background-color',
>       'green'
>     );
>   }
> }
> ```

inner-component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-inner',
  providers: [ColorService],
  templateUrl: './inner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inner.component.css'],
})
export class InnerComponent {}
```

app-component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  // providers: [ColorService],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ColorService {
  color = 'cyan';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Long story short it's because of Host decorator. when using the host decorator you are restricting the injector to only use the providers of child elements of the host element not the host element itself.
to fix your issue you can use viewProviders instead of providers to inject the  colorService to the inner component to be injected the way you want it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-inner',
  viewProviders: [ColorService],
  templateUrl: './inner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inner.component.css'],
})
export class InnerComponent {}
```

you can check this [article](https://admin.indepth.dev/a-curious-case-of-the-host-decorator-and-element-injectors-in-angular/) for more information.

Comment: sorry, but innerComponent is my host component. It has 2 child components: superinner and superinner2. superinner2 has providers array. superinner need to display to console color variable, it also has @Host(). 
However console dont has displayed value. https://stackblitz.com/edit/at-ng-14-router-jqebgx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsuperinner2%2Fsuperinner2.component.ts

Comment: @Sergey I don't think you can provide it from sibling. that's not the way that it has been designed to work. you can take a look at here https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#resolution-rules